# Trigger.io ui enhancement on Android doesn't apply to datetime-local

Tags: android, trigger.io

I've got a HTML5 hybrid app that I want to wrap in trigger.io for deployment.  On iOS, I've been able to use

```
<input type="datetime-local" ... />
```

To get an actual string for the date and time that I want, and to give my users the native date time picker.  Doing this in Android, however, just renders the field as a text box with the ISO formatted time in it.
If I use

```
<input type="datetime" ... />
```

I'm given the native date picker, followed by the time picker (I can live with that) but when "OK" is pressed, the value of the text box is what the time would be in GMT.  I don't want to see GMT, I want (basically) a string of the date and time that was entered.

I've had a look in the *all.js* file for trigger.io, which has a line like this:

```
var q=function(t){if(t.getAttribute("data-forge-fixed")!="yes"&&(t.type=="date"||t.type=="datetime"||t.type=="time")){
```

Note, it's missing the "datetime-local", like so:

```
var q=function(t){if(t.getAttribute("data-forge-fixed")!="yes"&&(t.type=="date"||t.type=="datetime-local"||t.type=="datetime"||t.type=="time")){
```

If I edit the file, and save this change, then re-compile my app, all of the changes to *all.js* are overwritten back to the most recently downloaded version of trigger.io.

Does anyone have a way around this, or is this a bug that I have to wait for them to fix before I can do any more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in our code, sorry about that. We'll make sure a fix is deployed by the end of the week.

I wouldn't recommend this in general, but if you want to work around it now you could edit all.js in `.template/android/assets/forge/all.js` within your app folder, this only gets replaced when a full server side build is run.

Comment: Thanks for that, any tips on how I avoid doing a full server side rebuild?  I normally go to the forge tab, select Run-> Android and it pushes to my device, but I guess this is what re-builds the all.js file?

Comment: A server side rebuild only happens if the app config changes or we push a new update which needs to be downloaded. If you do Run->Android and the last time you did it your config was the same then it will only do a local rebuild using whats in the `.template` folder.